# Uniqueness of smooth/symplectic/etc structure

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

It is well-known that every topological manifold $M$ of dimension $\le 3$ admits a unique smooth structure. That is to say for any choice of atlas on $M$ like $A$ and $B$, the smooth manifolds $(M, A)$ and $(M, B)$ are diffeomorphic.

My question is whether a similar result is known for symplectic or riemannian manifolds. For instance is it true that $(S^2, \omega_1)$ and $(S^2, \omega_2)$ are symplectomorphic for any two symplectic forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ on the $2$-sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is very far from true for symplectic or Riemannian structures; if this were true then symplectic and Riemannian geometry would be very boring!

Riemannian structures have local invariants coming from curvature and can be distinguished by those: if two Riemannian surfaces are isometric then in particular there must be a diffeomorphism between them which respects Gaussian curvatures, so for example the flat metric on $S^1 \times S^1$, which has zero Gaussian curvature everywhere, is not isometric to the metric coming from a typical embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has points with positive, negative, and zero Gaussian curvature.

Symplectic structures don't have local invariants, but they do have global invariants. A simple example that comes to mind is the cohomology class $[\omega] \in H^2(X, \mathbb{R})$ of the symplectic form, or more precisely the relationship between that cohomology class and the image of $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$. In particular, some symplectic forms have the property that their cohomology classes lie in the image of $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ and some don't, and this distinguishes symplectic forms on $S^2$. (You can say more: you can compare $[\omega]$ to a generator of $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$, which is equivalent to looking at the symplectic volume of $S^2$. This can be any nonzero positive real number.)

(Riemannian metrics also have global invariants, for example the Riemannian volume if that is finite.)

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu. It all makes sense now. Since you wrote about cohomology classes, it brought another question to my mind. Is there anything special about the cohomology class of "canonical" symplectic forms such as the ones on cotangent bundles that distinguishes them from the rest of symplectic forms on the manifold?

Comment: @Sam: the symplectic form on a cotangent bundle is always trivial in cohomology, since it is the differential of the tautological $1$-form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_one-form). I don't know what other examples you have in mind, but from the perspective of geometric quantization it's natural to single out the examples where $[\omega]$ lies in the image of $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$: these are the symplectic manifolds which admit prequantum line bundles (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/prequantum+line+bundle).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, cotangent bundle with its canonical symplectic form admits a prequantum line bundle whereas for instance not all coadjoint orbits with their canonical symplectic forms have this property. Am I right?

Comment: @Sam: yes, you can pick the trivial line bundle with connection given by $d$ plus the tautological $1$-form.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your last question, the answer is no, because a symplectic form on $S^2$ is a volume form, and its integral over $S^2$ is a global invariant under symplectomorphisms. However, it's interesting to note that the integral the only invariant: a 1965 [paper by Moser](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-120-02/S0002-9947-1965-0182927-5/S0002-9947-1965-0182927-5.pdf) [M] showed that if $M$ is a compact, connected, oriented manifold, then any two volume forms on $M$ with the same integral are related by a diffeomorphism.

[M] J. Moser, "On the volume elements on a manifold." Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 120, 286–294 (1965).